# Task cancellation, when?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

For an implementation of an API I'm making I want users to be able to cancel their tasks (Task). I figured out I would need a `CancellationTokenSource` so I could create a `CancellationToken` from the former. Now that I'm at the point of handling the cancellation request (`IsCancellationRequested`/`ThrowIfCancellationRequested`) I'm a bit confused. What would be the proper time to check/do this?

For example (fictitious):

```
async Task<int> DoStuff(int number, CancellationToken token) {
    // 1. Here, callee-site?
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    var resultTask1 = _database.GetSomeDataFromDatabase(token); // 2. Inside this method?
    var resultTask2 = _service.SomeRestCall(token); // 2. Inside this?

    // 3. Here, before the tasks return?
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    var result1 = await resultTask1;
    var result2 = await resultTask2;

    // 4. In memory processing, here?
    foreach(var item in result1)
    {
        // ...
    }

    foreach(var item in result2)
    {
        // 1. Here?
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await _fileSystem.Save(fileName, item, token); // 5. Inside this?
    }

    // 6. Here probably doesn't make sense though, the result is already retrieved?
    return 123;
}
```

What is best-practice for task cancellation?

Comment: I think if the task is small, you could put the cancellation check just before returning. If the task is quite long, you could put at multiple places (taking care of rolling back if cancelled). Finally, if there is a long loop, you can put the cancellation check inside the loop. It's just my opinion. Someone wiser may have a reasonable and better answer.

Comment: @displayName: Why? That's just an illusion. Everything have already been saved.

Comment: @jgauffin: Even though I explicitly said that it is my *opinion* and that *people may be wiser*, I still have one person questioning me about my humble opinion. :) Anyways.. is my updated comment better?

Comment: @displayName: I did not mean to offend you. a) I just wanted to point it out for the OP b) Also wanted to see if I had missed something

Comment: @jgauffin: 1) No offence taken. 2) Thanks to you, we have a better comment and a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be the proper time to check/do this?

For CPU-bound methods, it would be proper to call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` periodically. E.g., if you had a tight processing loop, you may want to call it every few hundred iterations or so.

However, it sounds like your situation is all I/O-bound (naturally asynchronous). In this case, it's best to *just pass the token down*. Higher-level asynchronous methods can just pass the token along. At the lowest level, if the API does not support `CancellationToken` directly, then it's generally best to use `CancellationToken.Register` to implement a true cancellation of the asynchronous operation. Of course, if the lowest-level API does support `CancellationToken` directly, then just pass it through.

Answer (score 3):

Cancelling is typically done when waiting for operations that take time. For instance waiting on IO operations or doing CPU-based calculations.

In your example there is really no need to cancel at #1, #2 and #6 since they just blaze through without a delay.

It would however make sense to check for cancellation in #4 if the list is large or if the computation takes time.

Finally #5 is a winner since IO isn't fast. However, doesn't `_fileSystem.Save` throw `TaskCancelledException`? In that case it's already been taken care of.

*Do note that by taking a cancellation token you also say that things are revertable. If not, be crystal clear in the documentation that cancelling will just abort those computations that have not been saved yet.*

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing called "Best-Practice". Usage of it may differ in different scenarios.

Basically the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is used to prevent running any extra line of code when Cancellation is asked. Think of it as below type check:

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested) 
    throw new OperationCanceledException(token); // break the processing immediately
```

Now its up to you to decide which code section should stop execution when a cancellation is requested. As @Jgauffin suggested LongRunning code sections would be a great place to put such checks. Also if you have multiple areas in your e.g. in given sample 2 for loops then you can use in both to avoid further processing once cancellation is asked.